# Ошибка : could not build Objective-C module 'SwiftDate'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

Ставил SwiftDate как под, и как фрэймворк, и все равно каждый раз xcode выдает ошибку о модуле objective c.
Обновить под так же не получается, так как новая версия swiftdate несовместима с Swift 2.3. Не знаю, как решить эту проблему. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Какая версия Swift?

Comment: В проекте сейчас Swift 2.3

Answer (score 1):

Пропишите podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'YourTargetProject' do
use_frameworks!
pod ‘SwiftDate’, :git => 'https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate.git', :branch => 'feature/swift_23’
end
```

и сделайте

```
pod update
```

Comment: Все, работает, спасибо!